# Independent kernel not executing concurrently

Tags: cuda

I'm implementing a Radon-like transform in CUDA, but I can't seem to get all performance out of my GeForce TITAN (**EDIT: apparently I do, see comments**). In order to optimize this, I thought of executing the kernels concurrently since they require only minimal data transfers, but I can't manage to get kernels to execute at the same time.

A typical profile run looks like this:
[image]

This is with "concurrent kernel support" enabled, compiling and generating code for sm_35 using CUDA 5.5 (RC). Overlap is minimal, and hardly worth it.

I've read a bit about concurrent kernel execution, and tried different things to get it right:

- Launch the kernel in different streams
- Interleave kernel launches, e.g. first launch kernel A n times using n streams, then launch kernel B n times using the same n streams, etc (although this might not be necessary any more for Kepler; the hardware managed to partially overlap kernels even when launched non-interleaved)
- Make sure that kernels don't use the same global memory (although I don't know whether that matters)
- Make sure that kernels don't use too much shared memory (the rotation kernels doesn't use any)

I don't get why the rotation kernels don't overlap more. Am I resource constrained, and if so, how can I find this out? If I use more diverse kernels it manages to parallelize a bit more, for example in this one,

[image]

but I think it should do better...

**EDIT: removed the 20% figure since I cannot reproduce it, and it seems to be wrong as well**

Comment: Which Nsight utilization metrics are you referencing that states that SM usage is 20%? The highlighted rotate_kernel launches 725 * ((725 + WARP_SIZE - 1) / WARP_SIZE) = 725 * 23 = 16675 warps which will fully fill the GPU 16675 warps / 46 warps/SM / 14 SM = ~26 times. It's highly unlikely this kernel has 20% SM utilization. Can you provide more information on the Visual Profiler metrics and on the kernel. You diagram meets my expectations given the data you provided.

Comment: About what statistic are you talking about exactly when you say 'NSight only reports 20% of the SMs to be in use' ? Titan has 14 SM and that is not divisible by 5 so how do you come up with 20%? Anyway... looking at the grid and block configuration in one of your images - block size [1,725,1] looks quite strange, why would you set the x dimension to 1? Ignoring that for a second, using 725 threads per block will allow you to run only 2 blocks per SM simultaneously and you want to launch a grid with 725 of blocks.

Comment: I see Greg already did the math too... and i agree with him, given the grid&block configuration the timeline looks to me as i would expect it to be.

Comment: And you guys seem completely correct; I cannot reproduce the 20% metric, sorry for the misinformation. So this means I am resource constrained, and adding streams won't help, right?

Comment: @RoBiK: I use the 1x725x1 thread block size because it matches the way the subsequent part of the algorithm works, it computes data over rows so I grouped all pixels in a row using threads. Does this hurt performance?

Comment: @maleadt i am not sure, it should not have any performance impact but the compiler sometimes works in mysterious ways... it wouldn't completely surprise me if the compiler somehow missed some optimization because of this "non-standard" threads to block-dimensions mapping

Comment: @maleadt and to answer your question, yes, you are resource constrained - in this case the restriction comes from maximum number of threads per SM (2048 for CC 3.5). Maybe you cold partition your problem differently.

Comment: @maleadt How is your processing? For each rotation angle you calculate the projection? Each projection line assigned to a different thread and then you loop over the rotation angles?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based in an erroneous interpretation of profiler output. There is no real problem here to solve.